# What's wrong with this Ruby on Rails & jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

So I'm building an app that let's a user paste the url of a video, and then using the embedly jquery API it outputs the thumbnail. Then, when clicking the thumbnail, the embedded video appears.

However, I get this error in my controller:

```
NoMethodError in VideosController#create

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.save
```

Here's my video controller:

```
def new
  @video = Video.new
end

def create
  @video = Video.new(params[:video])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @article.save
      format.html #{ redirect_to(@video, :notice => 'Article was successfully created.') }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

Here's my application.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("li a").embedly({}, function(oembed, dict){
  if ( oembed == null)
    return;
  var output = "<a class='embedly' href='#'><img src='"+oembed.thumbnail_url+"' /></a><span>"+oembed.title+"</span>";
  output += oembed['code'];
    $(dict["node"]).parent().html( output );
});
   $('a.embedly').live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('li').find('.embed').toggle();
  });
});
```

And here's my `new.html.erb` view:

```
 <%= form_for(@video) do |f| %>
 <% if @video.errors.any? %>
   <div id="errorExplanation">
     <h2><%= pluralize(@video.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this video from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @video.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :video_url %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :video_url %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>

 <div id="video_div">
<li><a href="<%= @video.video_url %>">Video</a></li>
 </div>
```

What am I doing wrong here? What are the next steps I need to take to make this work?

P.S. I include all the necessary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the video controller you're trying to save `@article`. You want to save `@video`.

Comment: That means you don't have a `create.html.erb` view. At this point we're really getting into a different problem than your original question.

Comment: That's because you probably don't have a view for the create action.  In practice, most people will do a redirect to an action displaying the record (e.g. show, index or whatever you prefer).

Comment: yeah, I realized that so I just redirect back to the `new` view with `format.html { render :action => "new" }` in the controller. However, now the thumbnail of the video doesn't appear. There's just a link that says "video" that takes you to the youtube video.

Comment: Right; you will want to return a different response to an ajax request than if it was a "normal" http request. You could return an html fragment or some json to work with back on the client side.

Comment: yeah, so i do something like `format.js` or `format.json` in the controller? and what's the html fragment I should be returning? Sorry for the noob questions lol

Comment: it really depends - if you're only going to allow creation via ajax, then you're safe with returning a partial (this would be an html fragment). if you want regular and ajax posts to work, i would return json from an ajax call.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to return json from an ajax call. Could you please provide an example, or at least point me to a source that could teach me this within an RoR setting?

Answer (score 2):

```
def create
  @video = Video.new(params[:video])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @article.save
```

video or article?